# Use mysql column values as php variable

Tags: php, mysql

I have an SQL query for a table with about 30 columns and would like to work with those columns values in variables without defining each and everyone first? What is the best way to do so in your opinion? I have googled a lot, but haven't really found what I'm looking for. Here is the query I am using:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'customername', 'password');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = 1";
$customer = $pdo->query($sql)->fetch();
echo $customer['first_name']." ".$customer['last_name']."<br />";
```

Comment: May I ask why? Isn't it better to keep them contained in the array you already have instead of cluttering the namespace with more variables?

Comment: I have the problem, that as soon as I start another query, those values from the first are somehow gone.

Comment: Are you reusing the variable names for the second query? Then yes, they will be overwritten. Use separate variable names, if you want to keep the data. Example (second query): `$customer2 = $pdo->query($sql)->fetch()`. Now you have both `$customer` and `$customer2`.

Comment: Thank you, Magnus! That helped. And sorry to all others, if my question was too stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'customername', 'password');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE id = 1";
$customer = $pdo->query($sql)->fetch();
extract($customer);
echo $first_name." ".$last_name."<br />";
```

But if you use this, your code will hardly readable. The original $customer['fieldname'] is the best way.

Comment: I need another query with another ID and those variables on that page, so the variables from the second query would probably overwrite the first ones, right?

Comment: @vloryan - If the result from the other query have the any of the same column names then, yes, those will be overwritten.

Comment: yes. If it's wrong for you, you can modify it with the extract function's second parameters. http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php Or you can use a prefix, if you set it this prefix will auto add to all extracted variables.